# 12.10 with GeForce GT630 can not have driver installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10, graphics

i have newly installed 12.10 ...

it feels good until i tried to install the graphic driver ...

i have these drivers ...

```
 model    : GK107 [GeForce GT 630]
 vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation 
 driver   : nvidia-experimental-310 - distro non-free
 driver   : nvidia-current - distro non-free recommended
 driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
 driver   : nvidia-current-updates - distro non-free
 driver   : nvidia-experimental-304 - distro non-free
```

which `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` can boot the system and show me desktop ...

although it shows some strange pictures like mosaic ...

when i installed other drivers and reboot ... system hangs on the screen below ...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2WvS.jpg

however when this screen appears ...

i can still visit the apache2 on this machine via another device ...

i think that means the system not dead but just can not bring me to the graphic interface ...

i ran ubuntu 11.04 before on same machine ... this situations never happen ...

i am stucked here and do not know what can i do ... will any one help ..?

`xrandr` says below when i can see desktop ... i am not sure whether this is useful or not ...

```
 xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
 Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1440, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 2560 x 1440
 default connected 2560x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    2560x1440       0.0*
```

at last ... **thank you for your reading** ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems someone discussed this issue (and other NVIDIA GeForce GT630 issues) back in september:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055636  ?

Besides I have in my own search for Ubuntu-supported graphics cards found these interesting pages at nvidia corp.:

ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/310.19/README/index.html

Describes how to install nvidia-drivers in a Linux system (hope it will work in ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 too!). Here

ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/310.19/README/supportedchips.html

is a list (exhausting and up-to-date?) of supported NVIDIA GPU Products for a Linuxx86 system from the same nvidia ftp site. GeForce GT 630 is listed there, so it seems there is some light at the end of the tunnel.

And last - but not least! -, I believe this section at ubuntu.com on nvidia, will be very helpful to all nvidia card problems:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

PS. I got all this info from another AskUbuntu discussion (on another nvidia graphic card), except my last link. Lesson learned: It pays to do a more thorough research on the problems. But I would agree, that its difficult for the newcomer to get fast results from the ubuntu-forums. Hope it will all improve with time, I am sure it will :-)